# 960 Grid System. Кто использует?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Интересно мнение о таком css-фреймворке (да забавное название) как [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/).
Вроде для дизайна шалон хороший, но вот для верстки не знаю.
Напрягает даже не то, что надо подключать маленький js-файлик, а то оправдан ли геморой использования стандартного css с разметкой.
Вобщем как говориться, "нас и тут не плохо кормят", стоит ли заморачиться? Поделитесь опытом, мыслями на этот счет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую похожий по смыслу [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/). Если для вас обычная верстка с нуля, блоками, не является раздражающим, ужасным, скучным и нудным процессом, то css фреймворки вам ни к чему. Если вам нравиться накидать 4-5 div'ов и иметь кроссбраузерную структуру сайта, то заморачиваться стоит, тем более что после того как вы просто прочитаете css все станет понятно.

Comment: ясно. Честно верстка много времени отнимает, особенно кроссбраузерная. Интересно в таком случае сравнить css фреймворки.

Comment: Я тоже использую blueprint, он по сути основан на 960 Grid + добавленные некоторые css твики для более удобной работы с формами, типографикой и некоторыми прочими элементами.  

Но все эти фреймворки надо тоже использовать с умом, сетка используется для разметки базовых блоков, не стоит все подряд на неё лепить, а то такой подход недалеко от табличной верстки уходит.